# What is the adjective for this kind of presentation of data?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, expressions, adjectives

For example, one can state

> Jane is a student. She is 20 years old. Jane likes swimming and reading. Jane's closest friends are Carmen, Mia and Alison.

Otherwise, this can be stated as

> Name: Jane
>
> Occupation: Student
>
> Age: 20
>
> Hobbies: Swimming; Reading
>
> Friends: Carmen; Mia; Alison

How I can correctly describe this second method with an adjective?

Comment: If you want something techie, put it in bulleted form.

Comment: The effort to pigeonhole data is categorization. The effort to force an orderly presentation is collation. I'd call the result a list. The data is listed by category.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for adjectives, I suggest **"summarized", "brief", "concise" or "compact"**.

> - [**summarize**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/summarize) - to make a summary or make a summary of.

- "here you can see a summarized review of..."
- "please, prepare a summarized record of..."
- "I'm going to present a summarized overview of..."

Comment: Thanks! I need such an adjective to describe the data representation method in a web app project. Isn't there any other, more technical-like term?

Comment: Oh, thanks! Anyways, this is just an example of data presentation. My app project is not on persons. It is just technical data that can be shown in a technical way, not in sentences and regular text. I suppose it is something like a *registry* or *form*...?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps **"itemised"** , since the description of Jane has been "broken down into constituent parts". The properties or attributes which describe Jane have been itemised.

Comment: I like itemized, but please give the source and link for your definition, notify me, and I will upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the adjective "Tabulated" form. In a typical tabulated form, keys and values are used.

"Key" is the identifier for a "value" corresponding to it. In a tabulation, as in systematic data arranged through spreadsheets, keys are either implicit or explicit. In the example quoted in the question, "Age", "Name", "Occupation" etc. are keys, and "20", "Jane" etc. are the associated values. An advantage of data arranged in terms of keys and values is that many similar records can be handled uniformly.

One example web page on which the phrase "tabulated form" is used can be found here:
https://www.mtt.org/tabulated-chapter-information

Comment: "Key" seems a rather 'techie' name.  Why not just call it the "Identifier", which is the word you've used to explain "key"?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It sounds techie, but I guess there is no need to be averse to it! Both the words, "key" and "identifer", are used for the same reason. I would prefer to keep it in rather than remove it.

Comment: Whether or not one uses 'techie' words surely depends on the audience - whether you're addressing techie people or the general public.